Is there an easier way to write this down and prevent duplicate code?
I am using middleman (Ruby on Rails) with HAML.
I have code like this at the beginning of each page:
- if pageversion == "test"
   - domain = data.testvars.domain
   - action_url = data.testvars.openlocker_url
   - lockergroup = data.testvars.lockergroup

- else
  - domain = data.prdvars.domain
  - action_url = data.prdvars.openlocker_url
  - lockergroup = data.prdvars.lockergroup

but I want to know if it possible to do something like this:
domain = data.#{pageversion}vars.domain
...
so every time it parses #{pageversion} and uses the output to create either data.testvars.domain or data.prdvars.domain.
So I'd like to either specify which .yml file to use based on #{pageversion} or interpret the string before as part of the name of a variable to look in the correct file.
Any idea how to do this?
My current way of doing it involves a lot of duplicate code and trying to do it any other way has yielded errors only.

You need to pre-assign the correct one, before using it:
data_vars = pageversion == "test" ? data.testvars : data.prdvars

Then you can use assigned value without dublicate code:
domain = data_vars.domain
action_url = data_vars.openlocker_url
lockergroup = data_vars.lockergroup


This is indeed what I was looking for. Can't believe it was that simple. I assume the ? data.testvars : data.prdvars is the if-else.

yes it is one line if else statement, you can use it for short conditions, like this one.

"I want to know if it possible to do something like this:" domain = data.#{pageversion}vars.domain.
You can use Object#public_send to accomplish this goal as well assuming that pageversion == 'test' or pageversion == 'pdr'.
Example:
domain = data.public_send("#{pageversion}vars").domain
action_url = data.public_send("#{pageversion}vars").openlocker_url
lockergroup = data.public_send("#{pageversion}vars").lockergroup

You could obviously set a local variable to avoid the duplication of public_send e.g.
data_set = data.public_send("#{pageversion}vars") if data.respond_to?("#{pageversion}vars")


Small follow-up: what does your solution have as benefit over the marked one?

@ZundraDolo it provides flexibility in the event that #{pageversion} can be more than just A or B (ternary). For instance if you also had a pageversion = 'example' and corresponding methods for pageversionexample this would still work. Additionally it answers the actual question you asked as shown in the first sentence.
